# How do I cache an image before it gets uploaded to the server, and prevent user from deleting the image

Tags: android, image, caching, firebase, image-uploading

I would like to know how can I prevent my users from deleting an image from the internal storage (for example, a photo) before it gets uploaded to the server.

I am using Firebase as my backend, and every works fine. But, if the user deletes the image before it can get uploaded (this happens because if there is not the internet I resume the upload once the user phone connects to the internet) my app crash because the route does no exist.

And I know I can check if the file exists, and do something else, but, since people is uploading important information, a placeholder will be not an option.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your app does not have to crash of course. Make it robust first. Catch the exception.

Comment: `And i know i can check if the file exist, and do something else`. Something else? Why? You just should not start uploading.

Comment: `would like to know how can i prevent my users from deleting an image from the internal storage `. Users cannot delete files from internal storage. Only from external storage and removable media.

Comment: I can catch the exception, but as i said, since is personal information, i can not just use a placeholder instead of the actual picture.

Comment: Catch it. And the rest of what you said is nonsense. And you did not react to most of the things i said.

Comment: Ok, i catch the exception, but the image does not exist. So, my question is, how do i prevent user for deleting that image before it can be uploaded.

Comment: You still did not react to what i said: Users cannot delete files from internal memory.